# Floated elements in IE7 acting weirdly

Tags: css, css-float, internet-explorer-7

I know there are a lot of posts here pertaining IE7 and float issues and I have had no luck reading through the multitude of issues.

We have an `a` wrapped inside a `div` tag that is floated left with paragraphs that should wrap around this. In all browser is works great... except for IE7. There it is shrinking the size of the div of the two paragraphs that should be floated to the size of space that is left between the `div/link` and the sidebar, which creates a large void where the second paragraph should wrap underneath the `div/link`.

You can visit the site at [dev.whitehardt.com](http://dev.whitehardt.com). Please view this in one of the better browsers to see how it is supposed to look.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: have you tried setting a height & width for your div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Omit the `zoom` style, or change it to `normal`.

```
p {
    zoom: normal;
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/K6n2M/

Comment: @WHWebDev - Worked for me: http://jsfiddle.net/K6n2M/.  To be fair, I'm running IE9 in IE7 mode.  Do you see different results when you view the jsfiddle?

Comment: Hmm, it is working now...must have missed something yesterday. Thanks!